# Copy and execute file via rdesktop

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I successfully conntected to a windows machine in **LAN** via `grdesktop`. Now I would like to have a script which copies a `*.bat` file and executes it on the windows machine via `rdesktop`. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
rdesktop -u someuser -p somepass IP -r disk:X=/home/user/somedir_with_script/ \
-s X:\scriptname.cmd
```

or

```
rdesktop -u someuser -p somepass IP -r disk:X=/home/user/somedir_with_script/ \
-s "cmd \C X:\scriptname.cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your examples with -s "notepad X:\myfile.txt" and -s "notepad" but notepad didn't start.

Answer (score 0):

Ok windows is soooo funny ;) Im try this on Windows XP now..and You must do something like this:

```
echo foo > /home/mariusz/test/bar.txt
rdesktop -r disk:Q=/home/mariusz/test 192.168.85.160 -s 'cmd /C "timeout /T 5 && notepad \\TSCLIENT\Q\bar.txt"'
```

Comment: This also doesn't work on my XP machine. I also tried -s 'cmd /C "notepad \\TSCLIENT\X\abcde.txt"'. BTW, timeout works on Windows 7, not on XP.

Comment: I made a bat file in Windows XP to emulate the time-out (based on pings). However you could try to open some existing file in your local partition, for example C. This should work. Then, if it works, you can try to do something more with remote storage.